# ViewPager Fragment not showing ProgressDialog

Tags: android

I have a tabbed activity that uses a ViewPager to navigate through three fragments.
when I load a fragment I have to load some data so I put the loading code inside an AsyncTask and I wanted to show a ProgressDialog while the data is being loaded.
This is the code in my AsyncTask:

```
public GetGeneralitaTask(Context c){
            this.c=c;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(c);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Caricamento...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }@Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        the loading part....
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Log.e("ending ", "second task");
    }
```

then in the Fragment onCreateView I call:

```
getGeneralitaTask=new GetGeneralitaTask(getActivity());
    getGeneralitaTask.execute();
    try {
        getGeneralitaTask.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but nothing is shown... the wiew just stands still 'til the data is loaded and populates the views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

> getGeneralitaTask.get();

It will cause the current thread to wait for the task to complete.